# How to create sha256 hash with salt

Tags: hash, google-bigquery, salt

I would like to migrate hash generation to BigQuery which has `SHA256`, but does not have salt as parameter.

For example in `R` I can do something like this:

```r
library(openssl)
sha256("test@gmail.com", key = "111")
# [1] "172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031"
```

**Update**

same with python based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384610/how-to-reproduce-an-sha256-based-hmac-from-r-in-python-3/):

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
print(hmac.new(b"111", b"test@gmail.com", hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())
# 172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope by "migrate", you mean to migrate the logic not the exact byte-wise output from R Sha256() function.

R is using hmacsha256 and looking at [Microsoft's HMACSHA256 class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_HMACSHA256__ctor_System_Byte___), it can be roughly expressed as:

> The HMAC process mixes a secret key with the message data, hashes the result with the hash function, mixes that hash value with the secret key again, and then applies the hash function a second time. The output hash is 256 bits in length.

```sql
create temp function hmacsha256(content STRING, key STRING)
AS (SHA256(
     CONCAT(
       TO_HEX(SHA256(CONCAT(content, key))), key)
       ));

SELECT TO_HEX(hmacsha256("test@gmail.com", "111"));
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               f0_                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4010f74e5c69ddbe1e36975f7cb8be64bcfd1203dbc8e009b29d7a12a8bf5fef |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Yun, may be answer here with python based solution will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384610/how-to-reproduce-an-sha256-based-hmac-from-r-in-python-3/

Comment: I found this is also good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430935/calculate-hmac-in-google-bigquery-sql . Also, its linked website matches exactly your output https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html. However, I haven't found the right way to convert it from sha1 to sha256

Comment: It should. You can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries) to try.

Comment: Yes, you have to upload them to your bucket.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @Yun I have managed to solve this.

To apply HMAC you will need to include external library [file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries) in the example function bellow.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION USER_HASH(message STRING, secret STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js
  OPTIONS (
    -- copy this Forge library file to Storage:
    -- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@0.7.0/dist/forge.min.js
    -- @see https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge
    library=["gs://.../forge.min.js"]
  )
  AS
"""
  var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
  hmac.start('sha256', secret);
  hmac.update(message);
  return hmac.digest().toHex();
""";


SELECT USER_HASH("test@gmail.com", "111");

-- Row  f0_
-- 1    172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, it could be improved to treat the null values from message or from secret:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION USER_HASH(message STRING, secret STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js
  -- copy this Forge library file to Storage:
  -- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@0.7.0/dist/forge.min.js
  -- @see https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge
  OPTIONS (library=["gs://.../forge.min.js"],
  description="From a given message and a key, we anonymize the hashed data using hmac_sha256 cryptography") AS """
  if (message == null){
    return null;
    } else if (secret == null){
    return message;
    } else {
    var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
    hmac.start('sha256', secret);
    hmac.update(message);
    return hmac.digest().toHex();
    }
  """;
```