# How to reproduce an SHA256-based HMAC from R in Python 3

Tags: python, r, sha256, hmac, salt

I am trying to reproduce salted `sha256` output from R code in Python:

```r
library(openssl)
res = sha256("test@gmail.com", key = "111")  
res
# [1] "172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031"
```

```py
import hashlib, binascii
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(='sha256', b'test@gmail.com', b'111', 0)
binascii.hexlify(dk)
# b'494c86307ffb9e9e31c4ec8782af6498e91272c011a316c242d9164d765be257'
```

How can I make output in python match R?

Comment: I have found this as well with more languages covered: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite reproduce your issue. The following keys match

In R:

```
library(openssl)
sha256("test@gmail.com")
#[1] "87924606b4131a8aceeeae8868531fbb9712aaa07a5d3a756b26ce0f5d6ca674"
```

In Python3:

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.sha256(b"test@gmail.com").hexdigest())
#87924606b4131a8aceeeae8868531fbb9712aaa07a5d3a756b26ce0f5d6ca674
```

---

### Update in response to your comment

The first thing to notice is that in R `sha256` with a non-`NULL` `key` argument will calculate the [hash-based message authentication code (HMAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). From `?sha256`:

> All hash functions either calculate a hash-digest for ‘key ==
>        NULL’ or HMAC (hashed message authentication code) when ‘key’ is
>        not ‘NULL’.

So if you want to use a key you will need to compare the resulting HMAC in R with the SHA2556-based HMAC in Python.

In R:

```
library(openssl)
sha256("test@gmail.com", key = "111")
#[1] "172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031"
```

In Python 3:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
print(hmac.new(b"111", b"test@gmail.com", hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())
#172f052058445afd9fe3afce05bfec573b5bb4c659bfd4cfc69a59d1597a0031
```

Comment: @Bulat I've made an edit, please take a look. I've also edited your title, since you're actually not asking how to reproduce the SHA256 but the SHA256-based HMAC.